# Disable the line limit wrap when Code Format is selected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, settings, android-preferences

Recently I set my line length **limit to 100 or 120** and I also **enabled an option that will wrap the code** that exceeded those limits to the next line, whenever I clicked Code Format.

Now **I want to disable that wrap and do it manually**, but I don't know where that setting was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android studio go to

> Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Keep
>   when reformatting and uncheck the checkbox Line Breaks

Comment: i misunderstood your question. have updated my answer. please check if it is working ? @J. K.

Comment: This setting is not turned on and it still wraps when I use Code Format

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33557531/2826147) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33531873/2826147).

Comment: The correct answer was "keep Line Breaks" checked so that I can manually wrap if I want to, and uncheck "Ensure right margin is not exceeded". I saw this in one of the links you provided

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->Settings->Editor->Code Style

There you'll find the two options "Right margin (columns)" and "Wrap when typing reaches right margin".

Comment: This setting is not turned on and it still wraps when I use Code Format.